# Why am I not getting the correct spherical harmonic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, software, spherical-harmonics

I defined $L_x$ and $iL_y$ in Mathematica. Then I used them to operate on $Y_2^1(\theta, \phi)$. Finally, I used $A_l^m = \hbar \sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m+1)}$.

**The code:**
[image]

But for some reason, my code returns $e^{2i\phi}\sqrt{\frac{15}{2\pi}}\hbar ^2\sin^2(\theta)$. The correct result should be $e^{2i\phi}\sqrt{\frac{15}{32\pi}}sin^2(\theta)$. Could someone help me figure out where the code went wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging code, not physics.

Comment: Actually, my mistake seemed to be a misunderstanding of the related physics equation (based on the answer by @NaOH). Therefore, it was on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You should have divided by $2\hbar$ in output[19] instead of multiplying. Reason:

For a raising operator
$L_{+}\,|l,m \rangle = \sqrt{(l+m+1)(l-m)}\,|l,m+1\rangle$

In your case we started with $|l=2, m=1\rangle$ and wanted to obtain $|l=2, m=2\rangle$:
$|2,2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2+1+1)(2-1)}}L_{+}\,|2,1 \rangle$